# Additional byte (0x00) arbitrarily added to the end Ethernet frames sent from Virtualbox VM

Tags: virtualbox, wireshark

I tried to send packets (happened with ICMP and HTTP) from VirtualBox VMs (Both Linux and Windows) to the host PC and capture with Wireshark on both sides.
On the VM, I saw it was sent in total frame size of 123 bytes. On the host computer I saw the packet received in total size of 124 bytes. The extra byte always has the value 0x00. Wireshark decoded the extra byte as "VSS-Monitoring Ethernet trailer". It is important to mention that packets which sent with total even size was received without the extra byte(for example 122 bytes). My question is why this happens, and how can I disable/stop this phenomenon, since it is disrupting my app to process the data correctly.